# Voltage meter ADC + serial: Bytes lost during communication

Tags: serial, adc, analog-sampling

I want to make a simple digital voltage monitor. So I have a sketch:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  int val = analogRead(A4);     // read the input pin
  val = 1;
  byte buf[4];
  buf[0] = 0;
  buf[1] = 0;
  buf[2] = val & 255;
  buf[3] = (val >> 8) & 255;
  Serial.write(buf, 4);             // report voltage value
}
```

When I tried to read serial buffer on PC host, I noticed that sometimes 1 byte can be lost, which lead to shifts and headache. How should the streaming be done?

---

PS.

- host os: win7 x64;
- language: c/c++
- com port library: [CSerial](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/serialcommunications/article.php/c2503/CSerial--A-C-Class-for-Serial-Communications.htm)

---

Loop is as follows:

```
typedef int32_t sample_t;
while (true) {
    int nBytesRead = serial.ReadData(lpBuffer, bufSize * sizeof(sample_t));
    size_t numRead = nBytesRead / sizeof(sample_t);
    if (numRead > 0)
        std::cout << "read: " << numRead << " samples\n"; // Calculate average here!
}
```

Comment: Either by printing it as simple ASCII, or by wrapping the values in a proper packet format with DLE.

Comment: @Majenko What is a "proper DLE packet"? I cannot find any reference on what DLE could stand for.

Comment: Data Link Escape. Your problem is you don't know where the data starts. You need a properly formed header with preamble, and a way of making bytes that appear in the data not appear to be a header byte. Or just use ASCII which restricts the valid data bytes to a very limited range.

Comment: @Majenko I thought i can prefix each values with 0xAAAA (like ethernet preamble stuff), then put a length field, then append postfix 0x5555 that means "transmission is done", and check if data length equals actual length - then is a valid packet.

Comment: That's the right kind of idea, yes. However you have to ensure that 0xAA or 0x55 never appear in your data. And that's where DLE comes in.

Comment: For example, replace `0xAA` with `0xFF 0x0A` then interpret that sequence at the receiver as `0xAA`. Of course, `0xFF` has to itself be escaped - as `0xFF 0xFF` for example.

Comment: So at the receiver, if you see `0xFF` then throw it away - but treat the next incoming character as something special.

Comment: @Majenko arduino 10-bit adc readings cannot exceed 1023. so these both cannot appear in data. i can even better place there 0xFFFF, 2 bytes length, 2*length bytes payload

Comment: One could. For example you may end up with 0xAA 0xAA 0x02 0x01 0x55 0x55 0x55

Comment: @Majenko so need to eliminate ending of a packet, replace it with length?

Comment: However, by the time you have done all this, your packet is now bigger than, for example, `1F3\n` which would suffice.  That's just 4 bytes maximum (less if the value < 256) - the size of just your pre- and postambles.

Comment: @Majenko You mean `Serial.println(val, HEX);` and parsing that on host?

Comment: That would give you `\r\n` as the ending - wasting a byte. `Serial.print(val, HEX); Serial.print("\n");` saves that one byte (if you care).  Then, yes, parse it on the host (which is simple enough).

Comment: The easiest way is to send the integer as ascii and do a atoi or atol on the pc. A '\n' or 'etx' at the end should be enough. If you want to be 100% sure, then a 'stx' at the begin and perhaps a checksum just before the '\n' or 'etx'. No HEX, but just Serial.print(val) for the data. The cable between the pc and the arduino is not a serial cable but a usb cable. A byte getting lost is almost impossible, something else is wrong.

Comment: @Majenko, That byte saved alot, now i am getting 5ksps instead of 3.5! Summing them up for a second and getting average leads to quite precise 16~20 bit voltmeter

Comment: @Jot It is solved, trouble was that i recieved data with 0 or 1 byte shift, and we found a simple way of solving it. sending via base-10 ascii would lead to poorer performance than sending hex

Comment: @xakepp35 For higher baudrates, you can try a arduino leonardo or micro. They have usb connected to the microcontroller itself and the communication is with usb speed because there is no real serial port. What about calculating the average in the arduino?

Comment: @Jot you think it will increase sampling rate (e.g better noise floor?) how much analogReads per second could it call? I have mega2560. How do i tie that to seconds in arduino? I need 1 measure per second, as precise as possible. Also summing up several thousand of samples would overflow 16bit integers.

Comment: The arduino mega has a 10-bits adc. Everything (linearity, noise, and so on) matches those 10 bits. I think a good start is an external 16-bits adc: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1085

Comment: @Jot when you sum up multiple samples, random noise is attenuated (If i sum up 16 samples, I could get at most 3 or 4 bits of extra precision, because random noise inside each sample will cancel itself out, and real DC data would properly sum up)

Comment: @xakepp35 yes, I always use the average of a number of samples to read dc voltages. But the linearity does not increase and that would be needed for a voltage meter. The overall precision requires a better adc than 10-bits.

Comment: @Jot for a 50 amps 220V wattmeter i calculated that i require 16 bit adc, to stay cool and precise less than 0.5W. Can i connect many 16-bit adc to single arduino board?

Comment: @xakepp35 The adafruit ADS1115 module has 4 analog inputs and 4 of those modules can be connected to a single i2c bus. For a wattmeter, what is the sample rate that you need? With many channels a adc with spi bus might be better, since the i2c bus is slow.

Comment: @Jot I need to measure up to 50a shunt, with precision more than "0.5W error per day"

Answer (score 0):

With help in a comments I've managed to deal with the task myself.

First of all, as @Majenko pointed out, I was dealing with some multi-byte data. So I need some control character, that separates packets. I choose hex output with '\n' delimeter as control character - that served good. I was able to read 3.5 to 5k packets per second (with voltage reading) from serial on the host.

Second improvement, credited to @Jot, is to stack some sequential values right in arduino, before sending.

Alongside with [increasing sampler frequency](http://yaab-arduino.blogspot.com/2015/02/fast-sampling-from-analog-input.html) that could be very good.

```
#define cbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) &= ~_BV(bit))
#define sbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) |= _BV(bit))

void setup() {
  sbi(ADCSRA, ADPS2);
  cbi(ADCSRA, ADPS1);
  cbi(ADCSRA, ADPS0);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  int val = 0;
  for( int i = 0; i < 32; ++i )
    val += analogRead(A0); 
  Serial.print(val, HEX);
  Serial.print("\n");
}
```

at the host recieve side, some simple conversion could be done:

```
#include "Serial.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

// sample to voltage
double s2v(int sample) {
    return 5.0 * (static_cast<double>(sample) / 1024);
}

int main() {
    std::ofstream ofs("test.csv", std::ios::out | std::ios::ate);

    size_t comPort = 3;
    size_t baudRate = 115200; // 57600;

    CSerial serial;
    if (serial.Open(comPort, baudRate))
    {
        std::cout << "COM" << comPort << " opened @" << baudRate << "bit/s\n";

        // serial recv buffer 
        size_t bufSize = 1048576;
        auto lpBuffer = new char[bufSize];

        // accumulator
        size_t nVals = 0;
        int nAcc = 0;

        // timer
        __time64_t destTime;
        __time64_t destTime2;
        _time64(&destTime);

        while (true) {
            SleepEx(10, false); // care of 100% cpu core usage, poll serial port lazily
            size_t nBytesRead = serial.ReadData(lpBuffer, bufSize * sizeof(lpBuffer[0]));

            //parse buffer:
            size_t cvtPtr = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < nBytesRead; ++i) {
                if (lpBuffer[i] == '\n') {
                    try {
                        lpBuffer[i] = '\0';
                        auto val = std::stoi(lpBuffer + cvtPtr, nullptr, 16);
                        nAcc += val;
                        nVals++;
                    }
                    catch (...) {
                        // ignore, or warn that serial recieved junk/empty packet
                    }
                    cvtPtr = i + 1;
                }
            }

            //check if doom had come!
            _time64(&destTime2);
            if ((destTime2 - destTime) > 0) {
                auto fVoltage = ( s2v(nAcc) / 32 ) / nVals;
                std::cout << fVoltage << "\t(" << nVals << " ksps)\n";
                ofs << destTime << "," << fVoltage << "," << nVals << "\n";
                if((destTime % 30 ) == 0) // care of disk, write only once in 30 seconds
                    ofs.flush();
                destTime = destTime2;
                nVals = 0;
                nAcc = 0;
            }
        } // while
    } // if opened
    return 0;
}
```

That gives voltmeter with high precision, about ±0.5mV, that is updated every second.

Also! It was stated about 10bit adc, 5.0V/1024 = 4.88mV, but i got some subthreshold oscillations in vivo, adding samples up. So you are wrong, noise can be attenuated and resolution can be artificially pumbed up, in a trade for increased sampling time. Here is 14bit ADC built on top of 10bit ADC: [image]. Its photovoltaic cell in a dark street, oscillations are caused by cars' front lights. Timescale is 1000 seconds per grid div

Comment: Don't you mean +-5mV? Because 5V / 1024 (10 bit) is about 4.9mV

Comment: @chrisl I mean i got 3-4 bits more resolution that was specified for arduino 10-bit ADC.